# Version scheme change of libc6 libraires from focal to jammy

Tags: 20.04, package-management, 22.04, dpkg, glibc

Hello Ubuntu  community,

I notice that the Version scheme changes on libc6 libraries from focal to Jammy  (i.e On the jammy libc6 packages i observe that on the libraries name minor version  has been dropped out and only major is present which is not the case in focal libc6 package).May I know the reason behind this decision, Is this the path (version scheme) that Ubuntu is taking forward for all other of its library packages and if possible is there any way to get old convention (libname major version. minor version)  back like installing some package or change settings

Example

libdl name on focal:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnux32/lib64/libdl-2.31.so

libdl name on jammy:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnux32/lib64/libdl.so.2

Link:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/libc6-amd64-x32-cross/filelist

https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/libc6-amd64-x32-cross/filelist

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change is from upstream glibc, see [the announcement for v2.34](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-August/129718.html):

> - Previously, glibc installed its various shared objects under versioned
>   file names such as libc-2.33.so.  The ABI sonames (e.g., libc.so.6)
>   were provided as symbolic links.  Starting with glibc 2.34, the shared
>   objects are installed under their ABI sonames directly, without
>   symbolic links.  This increases compatibility with distribution
>   package managers that delete removed files late during the package
>   upgrade or downgrade process.

I don't think this is configurable, nor that either glibc or Ubuntu will revert the change. You can try filing a bug report, though, if this actually does cause some problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was searching for this kind of official announcement about this change for a while